# Question about Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inclusion-exclusion

I have a set of independent events $\{B_1,B_2,...,B_k\}$ where $k\leq n$ for some integer $n>0$.

I know the following probabilities

$$
p(B_i) = (1-r^{\frac{n}{n-i}})\\
p(\overline{B_i} \cap B_j ) =p(\overline{B_i}) p(B_j) =  r^{\frac{n}{n-i}}(1-r^{\frac{n}{n-j}})\\
p(B_i \cap B_j ) =p(B_i) p(B_j) = (1-r^{\frac{n}{n-i}})(1-r^{\frac{n}{n-j}})
$$

for some $0<r<1$. Is there an easy way to compute the following probability?

$$
p(B_1 \cup B_2\cup B_3\cup...\cup B_{k-1}\cup \overline{B_k}) 
$$

I would use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to compute it
$$
p(B_1 \cup B_2\cup B_3\cup...\cup B_{k-1}\cup \overline{B_k}) = \sum_{r=1}^{k}
(-1)^{r+1}\left[\sum_{i_1<i_2<...<i_r<k}\prod_{j=i_1}^{i_r}p(B_j)+\sum_{i_1<i_2<...<i_{r-1}<k}p(\overline{B_k})\prod_{j=i_1}^{i_{r-1}}p(B_j)\right]$$

but I suspect it will just be a mess to derive a general formula. Any advice?

Comment: If the $B_i$ are independent, so are the $C_i$ where each $C_i$ is either $B_i$ or $B_i^\complement.$ Then $P(C_1 \cap \ldots \cap C_p) = \prod P(C_i).$ Recall that for any sets $A_\alpha,$ $\left\{ \bigcup\limits_\alpha A_\alpha \right\}^\complement = \bigcap\limits_\alpha A_\alpha^\complement.$

Comment: @WilliamM. yes, indeed this is what I have written in the last equation where I expanded the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Comment: I actually meant you to derive $P(B_1 \cup \ldots \cup B_{k-1} \cup B_k^\complement) = 1 - P(B_1)\cdots P(B_{k-1})(1-P(B_k)).$